# size_hint_max_x not setting a max limit on width

Tags: python, kivy

I'm taking a Udemy course on writing mobile apps with `Kivy` and `Python`. The lesson gets into setting `size_hint` and `size_hint_max` (or specifically, `size_hint_x` and s`ize_hint_max_x`). I don't get `size_hint_max_x`. The only thing the lesson explains is that when you set `size_hint_max_x` to `None`, the widget takes up the whole width (it doesn't explain why). It also directs me to the official documentation which defines `size_hint_max_x` as:

When not `None`, the x-direction maximum size (in pixels, like width) when `size_hint_x is` also not None.

Similar to `size_hint_min_x`, except that it sets the maximum width.

Sounds to me like I can set a maximum limit on the size of a button along the x axis. Not so.

Here's my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""

FloatLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'B1'
        size_hint_x: .5
        size_hint_x_max: .3

"""))
```

This produces this:

[image]

The button is still 50% of the window even though the `size_hint_max_x` is 30%. I would expect the button to be 30%.

The definition from the documentation says that `size_hint_max_x` is in pixels so I tried this:

```
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'B1'
        size_hint_x: .5
        size_hint_x_max: 100

"""))
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. The button is still 50% of the window which is more than 100 pixels. If I try setting `size_hint_x to` 200 I get the same results (the 100 pixel limit for max x not being honored).

What good is `size_hint_x_max` if it doesn't enforce a maximum size on widgets?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the `size_hint_max_x` is in pixels, and it's used to pass a maximun size when using the `size_hint`.

The only problem I see with your code is that you changed the order there in: `size_hint_x_max:`. When it should be `size_hint_max_x:`

Comment: It's likely that `size_hint_max_x` is converted to an integer at some point. The integer conversion of `0.3` is `0`.